# How to export Wordpress posts to XLIFF?

Tags: wordpress

How to export WordPress posts to XLIFF? I am looking for a neat way to do it with the help of PHP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XLIFF is just XML, so you could modify a plugin like [oxyXML](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oxyxml/), or even the built in RSS feed generator (`wp-includes/feed-rss2.php`) to generate the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code of this drupal module:
http://drupal.org/project/xliff

You can take the function in there and convert it for you needs.  they make use of the xliff2xml roundtrip tool that uses an xsl transformation for XML (or xhtml in your case) to xliff and vice versa